# Sum String-Length of two different nodes with Xpath - Sum two nodes string-length

Tags: xml, xpath, string-length

The following xpath does not seem to work:

```
//FullName[sum(string-length(FirstName) | string-length(LastName))>= 30]
```

Error:  Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

XML snippet

```
<FullName>
 <FirstName>somereallylongfirstnameguy</FirstName>
 <LastName>somereallylonglasttnameguyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv</LastName>
</FullName>
```

I know the sum function adds number together, and string length returns numbers.

The following expression works fine:

```
//FullName[string-length(FirstName) >= 1]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sum()` function [expects a node-set](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_sum.html), which you try to provide with your `string-length()` calls, but that fails. `sum()` does not appear to be the appropriate function here.

You can either just add up the lengths directly in the predicate:

```
//FullName[string-length(FirstName)+string-length(LastName) >= 30]
```

Or you can use concatenate first, then get the length:

```
//FullName[string-length(concat(FirstName,LastName)) >= 30]
```

Or, if your snippet is representative for all `FullName` elements, just consider the length of all text node contents of the context node like this:

```
//FullName[string-length() >= 30]
```

Comment: The last suggestion only works if the stylesheet specifies `<xsl:strip-space>`, otherwise the length will also include the whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of names can vary (such as Middle Initil, orefix, suffix, etc...), it is generally not possible to get the wanted sum with a single XPath 1.0 expression.

**In XPath 2.0 this is possible**:

```
//FullName[sum(*/stringlength()) ge 30]
```